# AHK - How to bind on hold and bind on a press to pause

Tags: autohotkey

I have the AHK script that I want to upgrade. Script displays in the center of your screen a red dot. I wonder how to make it work when you toggle some key or mouse button. And how to suspend it on any button click.

```
; reddot
x = 840
y = 525
w = 3
h = 3
Color = 0xFF0000
WS_EX_TRANSPARENT := 0x20
WS_EX_LAYERED := 0x80000
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow +LastFound
Gui, Color, % Color
Gui, Show, x%x% y%y% w%w% h%h% NA
WinSet, ExStyle, % "+" WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this to your existing script:

```
state:=True

;the 'q' key
q::
state^=1 ;Basically just inverts the value of the 'state' variable
if(state)
    Gui, Show
else
    Gui, Hide
return

;Shift + the 'Esc' Key
+Esc::Suspend, Toggle
```

See the AHK documentation for [`Hotkeys`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for how to remap which key (or key combinations) will trigger these effects.

Final/ Combined code:

```
; reddot
x = 840
y = 525
w = 3
h = 3
Color = 0xFF0000
WS_EX_TRANSPARENT := 0x20
WS_EX_LAYERED := 0x80000
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow +LastFound
Gui, Color, % Color
Gui, Show, x%x% y%y% w%w% h%h% NA
WinSet, ExStyle, % "+" WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

state:=True

;the 'q' key
q::
state^=1
if(state)
    Gui, Show
else
    Gui, Hide
return

;Shift + the 'Esc' Key
+Esc::Suspend, Toggle
```

Lmk if you need anything else